# Overloading malloc to track memory usage of third party libraries

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best strategy for profiling memory usage of my code (open source) and 3rd party code(closed source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192531/best-strategy-for-profiling-memory-usage-of-my-code-open-source-and-3rd-party-c)

I am thinking of implementing a memory tracking tool to track malloc's in my code by having a library that I will link in at compile time to override malloc with a macro to add some additional debugging info that will print some stuff to a log. Is it possible to possibly do this with a third party library that I do not have source code, or possibly debug libraries available? Can you link in a library like I am talking about to a third party library and it will use the methods (or macros) defined in my library?

Thanks

Comment: use valgrind, save yourself the hassle. Else search electricfence in your favourite search engine. Plus this site has LOTS of question on this very topic.

Comment: ...for example, here is a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910172/track-c-memory-allocations

Comment: ... until someone calls `sbrk()` to allocate memory :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that, malloc is a system call.

The binary libraries aren't actually calling malloc(), they're loading a library stored on your machine into memory. Then executing the function at the correct memory address.

Redefining malloc() wont do anything except confuse things.

Comment: Hmm, `malloc(3)` is most definitely NOT a system call, but a library routine. You are probably thinking of `brk(2)` and/or `mmap(2)` - the system calls UNIX libc relies on for memory management. It is not a system call on Windows either afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Use profiler: [AQTime](http://smartbear.com/products/development-tools/performance-profiling/) is a really good one for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what platform / OS you are trying to do that on:

- If you are using a RTOS on embedded device, you may be able to change the code directly in there too...
- If you are on Linux, you may be able to find the code somewhere and change it there to recompile, but you may have a pretty serious performance impact on your platform.
- For others, you can use a wrapper in your application, call it "os_malloc" or something like that and implement that function for any debugging or anything like that.

The last one is probably your safest bet no matter what...