# How can i get memory size allocated by my program?

Tags: c++, c, qt, memory, opencv

I write my project by c with opencv.
I want print info about allocated memory or memory used by my program.
Is there a functions, that give me the information about the memory ?
Finally I'm using Qt for Linux and Windows ,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This previous thread has some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192531/best-strategy-for-profiling-memory-usage-of-my-code-open-source-and-3rd-party

Answer (score 4):

You can write wrappers to `malloc` and `free` that track how much memory you're using.

EDIT: If you also want to intercept calls to malloc and free in external libraries, you will have to define them in a shared library and load it before libc. How you do this depends on your OS.

Comment: if you load a library and that uses the unwrapped `malloc`, is that memory used by your programn or not?

Comment: could you give me example about malloc as wrapper  and free .

Comment: @RemusRusanu it's absolutely possible indeed. One can call OS memory reservation functions directly. like `sbrk` (though unrecommended because it interferes with some malloc implementations). `memmap` which is used by modern mallocs, and gives isolated chunks of mem. `VirtualAlloc` on Win32, same concept. Or the `NTHeap` stuff too.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux you look into [your own process info pseudo-file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc):

```
/proc/[pid]/statm
Provides information about memory usage, measured in pages. The columns are:
size       total program size
           (same as VmSize in /proc/[pid]/status)
resident   resident set size
           (same as VmRSS in /proc/[pid]/status)
share      shared pages (from shared mappings)
text       text (code)
lib        library (unused in Linux 2.6)
data       data + stack
dt         dirty pages (unused in Linux 2.6)
```

On Windows you look at you own process [Process Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804621.aspx) performance counters:

> `Private Bytes` Shows the current number of bytes that this process has allocated that cannot be shared with other processes.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do some level of memory analysis of Code/Data segment during build time if you check elf, dump or map file. 
And GCC command line options for stack usage are: **-fstack-usage and -fcallgraph-info.**

Comment: -1 I am pretty sure the OP is asking for the memory allocated at runtime.